# Folding in Haskell, using more than one function

Tags: haskell, fold, accumulate

I have a list of integers based on letters. For example:

```
let charlist = map (ord) "ABCDEF"
```

`charlist` would then look like the following:

```
[65,66,67,68,69,70]
```

I also have a list of three functions: `(+)`, `(-)` and `(*)`. The list in this example looks like this

```
let funclist = [(+), (-), (*)]
```

I want to apply the functions **in order** between the elements in `charlist` (if there are more "spaces" in `charlist` than there are elements in `funclist`, you start over from the beginning of `funclist`) and calculate the final value **from left to right**, like the following:

```
s = ((((((65) + 66) - 67) * 68) + 69) - 70)
```

I was thinking about using `foldl`, but `foldl` seems to only work with one function. Is there any other way to do this? I would like to summarize this entire process in one function, if possible, though it's not a requirement.

Comment: I suggest you try to implement this using pattern matching and explicit recursion first. Once you've got a solution that works, there's still time to see whether it fits the pattern for a higher-order function such as `foldl` nicely.

Comment: You may want to use `cycle` in order to implement the feature that you start over from the beginning of `funclist` when you run out of elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whilst `foldl` may only apply one function, you can have different functions in your data. The trick it to attach the appropriate `+`, `-` or `*` function to your data. You're off to the right start:

```
funclist = [(+), (-), (*)]
```

But lets now make a infinite version of the above list, like `[(+), (-), (*), (+), (-), (*)...]`

```
infinite_funclist = cycle funclist
```

Lets assign the numbers we're going to fold over here. `first` is in this case `65`, `rest` is `[66..70]`

```
(first:rest) = [65..70]
```

Now we zip together `rest` and `infinite_funclist` to get `[(66,(+)), (67,(-)), (68,(*)), (69,(+)), (70,(-))]`. We start with `first`, and for every new element, we apply the operation that's in the second part of the current tuple to the current value and the first part like so:

```
result = foldl' (\acc (v, f) -> acc `f` v) first (zip rest infinite_funclist)
```

If we want to print the result we can do so like so:

```
main = print result
```

(Link to code [here](http://ideone.com/CkdIYD))

Comment: Thank you for this! This works perfectly. Straight-forward solution with a good explanation, making it possible even for a newcomer like me to understand. ;)

Answer (score 4):

In essence, this is a zip rather than a fold. Nicest would be

> > zipWith ($) (cycle funclist) charlist
>   [(65+), (66-), (67*), (68+), (69-), (70+)]

but because of left-associativity and initial element we need to do it a bit more wordy

> > let ptApplied = tail . zipWith (($) . flip) (cycle funclist) $ charlist
>   ptApplied = [(+66), (subtract 67), (*68), (+69), (subtract 70)]

Only then comes the fold

> > foldl' (flip ($)) (head charlist) ptApplied

Answer (score 1):

You can always pass more information through the accumulator of the fold, which can be used by your single function to *behave* as if it were a different function each time. Probably the simplest way to do this is to pass the current list of functions to be applied through the rest of the list in the accumulator.

```
Prelude Data.List> snd $ foldl' (\(f:fs, acc) x -> (fs, f acc x))
                                ((+):cycle funclist, 0) [65,66,67,68,69,70]
4351
```

(I inserted an extra `(+)` on the front of funclist so that the "real" plus comes between 65 and 66, rather than between the initial accumulator 0 and 65)

Comment: I like your answer; it helped simplify my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Who says you can't "pass variables" to foldl?

```
Prelude> let f = [(+), (-), (*)]

Prelude> let c = [65,66,67,68,69,70]

Prelude> foldl (\(a,i) val -> ((f!!(mod i 3)) a val,i + 1)) (head c,0) (tail c)
(4351,5)
```